# No USB devices android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I used to run my application in VIVO Y51L device. It's showing as No USB devices detected.

Developer options and USB debugging is ON, but it is still not detecting. What should I do??

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to avoid using bold letters and words unless they are very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to improper driver installation or adb. Although this should not have happened if you had it working earlier re-installing the drivers should fix this. I'd recommend you to download and run the [15 second adb installer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979). It would install adb system-wide and also give you an option to re-install the required google drivers.
Installing them should fix this. You can verify that your device is connected by opening the command prompt and typing `adb devices`. It should kill the daemon and restart it. Once you switch back to Android Studio and run it. Your device should show up there.

Good Luck.

Comment: @RahulJaiswal Im glad I could help